# Setting ScatterViewItem Minimum Drag Distance

Tags: c#, wpf, scatterview

How do I change the sensitivity of a ScatterViewItem? Sometimes I just want to tap it, but the dragging would trigger and move ScatterViewItem a little (by 1 or 2 pixels). How do I set a minimum distance to trigger dragging?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to do this